# how to make two condition check in logstash and write better configuration file

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am using logstash 1.4.2,

## I have logstash-forwarder.conf in client log-server like this

```
{
    "network": {
      "servers": [ "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000" ],
      "timeout": 15,
      "ssl ca": "certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    },
  "files": [
       {
          "paths": [ "/var/log/messages" ],
          "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
        },
        {

          "paths": [ "/var/log/secure" ],
          "fields": { "type": "linux-syslog" }
        }
         ]
}
```

=========================================================

In logstash server

### 1. filter.conf

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Asia/Kathmandu"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{WORD:messagetype}\]%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
  }
if [type] == "linux-syslog" {
date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Asia/Kathmandu"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
mutate { replace => [ "syslog_timestamp", "%{syslog_timestamp} +0545" ] }

  }
}
```

=======================================================

## 2. output.conf

```
output {
    if [messagetype] == "WARNING" {
 elasticsearch { host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

 if [messagetype] == "ERROR" {
 elasticsearch { host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

if [type] == "linux-syslog" {
 elasticsearch { host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

}
```

=======================================================

I want all the logs to forward from /var/log/secure and only ERROR and WARNING log from /var/log/messages, I know this is not a good configuration. I want someone to show me a better way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer to make decisions about events in the filter block. My input and output blocks are usually quite simple. From there, I see two options.

## Use the drop filter

The [`drop` filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/drop) causes an event to be dropped. It won't ever make it to your outputs:

```
filter {
    #other processing goes here

    if [type] == "syslog" and [messagetype] not in ["ERROR", "WARNING"] {
        drop {}
    }
}
```

The upside of this is that it's very simple.

The downside is that the event is just dropped. It won't be output at all. Which is fine, if that's what you want.

## Use a tag

Many filters allow you to add tags, which are useful for communicating decisions between plugins. You could attach a tag telling your output block to send the event to ES:

```
filter {
    #other processing goes here

    if [type] == "linux-syslog" or [messagetype] in ["ERROR", "WARNING"] {
        mutate {
            add_tag => "send_to_es"
        }
    }
}

output {
    if "send_to_es" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            #config goes here
        }
    }
}
```

The upside of this is that it allows fine control.

The downside of this is that it's a bit more work, and your ES data ends up a little bit polluted (the tag will be visible and searchable in ES).

Comment: thanks rutter!  the first one you suggested looks good to me. So do i have to simply add these lines in my filter.conf . Sorry to ask you a lot but am just a starter.

Comment: I think the problem is solved somehow now. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: how do I compare with 2 types of logs at the same if condition ?